# Выключение ОС Ubuntu при смене пользователя

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Имеется Ubuntu 16.04.
Загружено две графические сессии - рут и пользователь.
При смене пользователя на рут, система уходит в halt.

Journalctl:
`июн 18 18:11:16  compiz[1998]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_cracklib.so): /lib/security/pam_cracklib.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
июн 18 18:11:16  compiz[1998]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_cracklib.so
июн 18 18:16:29  compiz[1998]: ignoring low-UID user (0 < 1000)
июн 18 18:16:29  compiz[1998]: gkr-pam: the password for the login keyring was invalid.
июн 18 18:16:29  audit[1998]: USER_AUTH pid=1998 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/compiz" hostname=? addr=? terminal=pts/7 res=succe
июн 18 18:16:29  audit[1998]: USER_ACCT pid=1998 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/compiz" hostname=? addr=? terminal=pts/7 res=success'
июн 18 18:16:29  audit[1998]: CRED_REFR pid=1998 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/compiz" hostname=? addr=? terminal=pts/7 res=success'
июн 18 18:17:01  CRON[3767]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_cracklib.so): /lib/security/pam_cracklib.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
июн 18 18:17:01 CRON[3767]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_cracklib.so[/code]`

Вижу, что проблемы с библиотеками, но конкретно по моему случаю решения не нашел.
Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: большинство современных систем очень сильно не любит, когда пользователь логинится рутом в графическую среду. Да и не нужно это делать - всегда есть sudo.  В Вашем случае скорее всего права на файл выставлены не совсем так, как Вам хочется.

Comment: На файл /etc/sudoers ?

Comment: Я об этом файле ничего не говорил. Попробуйте не использовать рута напрямую.

Comment: проблема решилась установкой libpam_runtime и libpam_modules

Comment: @cryptoparty Ну так система Вам прям по русски говорила: "pam_cracklib.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога"! Раз нет - значит надо установить!